# Is it possible to have filter table/(search) results displayed upon return to the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been able through JS to overcome an autocomplete compatibility issue with a successful alternative to `autocomplete= "off"`. Only when I navigate through some pages and return back to the filter table/(search) page in question the results disappear! even though the search keyword is displayed in the input box still. So being completely stuck - the aim is to have the filter table/(search) page results displayed upon return to the page, if this is there is at all a possible simple solution?[image: (upon return after browsing around) search keyword - only without the results displayed][image: filter table/(search) - success!]

Comment: when returning to the page you can trigger the search method again, right ? if you have the searchkeyword saved just trigger the function with that searchitem.

Comment: OK but simply how? - that's what I'm asking in this question

Comment: Well you do have a search method which returns the search results, right ? just call that on page reload inside an if ( check if you have a search keyword or not, if yes, call the method )

Comment: I really don't want to **reload** the page. I simply want to return to the page and find that nothing has changed with the page. I simply want to return to the page as it was. As I see it if the keyword exists in the input box, then the results should still be displayed. Please bare in mind that this is less of a a search page though more a filter table results page

Comment: Would you like me to supply the source code?

Comment: You could store the string in localStorage? Possibly add a timestamp, if you don't want someone to come back after X months and have the input prefilled with the previous seach. :)

Comment: Yes that's a great idea, but it does slow things down somewhat. There must be a simpler solution when considering that I'm only using a table filter for the results. Some kind of little trigger seems to make sense, but that's the problem I'm having difficulty with figuring

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/ See this demo from another user has similarities to what I am doing, notice though when you navigate away from the the page and return the results are sill there! - this is what I'm aiming for

Comment: I wonder if anyone knows of plugin or some demo code that might be available. If someone could point me to this it would be helpfull